# Removing Specific Entries from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list with the following sample entries (Name & Disease):

```
1.  Name: Aimee Cholmondeley. Disease: German measles
2.  Name: Colin Anissina.     Disease: Diphtheria
3.  Name: Colin Anissina.     Disease: Malaria
4.  Name: Aimee Cholmondeley. Disease: Typhoid fever
5.  Name: Isaias Cheung.      Disease: Haemophilus Influenza
6.  Name: Isaias Cheung.      Disease: Scarlet fever
7.  Name: Sebastian Cutting.  Disease: Gingivitis
8.  Name: Juan Weiss.         Disease: Acquired Immunodeficiency Sydrome (AIDS)
9.  Name: Kaelyn Nauman.      Disease: Amebiasis
10. Name: Kaelyn Nauman.      Disease: Human Pulmonary Syndrome (HPS)
11. Name: Lyndsey Stapleton.  Disease: Chlamydia
12. Name: Lyndsey Stapleton.  Disease: Chlamydia
```

- **Same Name, Different Disease -> Remove Both!**
- **One Instance -> Keep**
- **Same Name, Same Disease -> Keep, but only one copy!**

Now, for some reason, .equals isn't working. So I can't simply do `if (arrayList.get(i).equals(arrayList.get(j)) then remove`. So I'm comparing names and diseases individually, using `compareTo` for comparing the diseases (which is working).

Here is what I tried:

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < IDArray.size(); i++){ //IDArray contains all the elements
>         int countFound = 0;
>         IdenPerson curr1 = IDArray.get(i);
>         for (int j = i + 1; j < IDArray.size(); j++) {
>                IdenPerson curr2 = IDArray.get(j);
>                if (curr1.name.toString().equals(curr2.name.toString())) { //If Name is same
>                    if  ((curr1.dis.toString().compareTo(curr2.dis.toString())) == 0) { // And Disease is same
>                        System.out.println(curr1.name.toString()); // Print that Name
>                        break;
>                    }
>                }
>                else {
>                    // If name is not same, and only repeated once ... how to do this?
>                }
>         }
>     }
> ```

```
public static class IdenPerson {
    String name;
    String dis;
}
```

Using the above, I can find the double copy elements but I cannot separate the single instance elements. Please help! I cannot use libraries external to Java.

Here's what the above ArrayList should look like when it works:

```
1. Name: Sebastian Cutting.  Disease: Gingivitis
2. Name: Juan Weiss.         Disease: Acquired Immunodeficiency Sydrome (AIDS)
3. Name: Lyndsey Stapleton.  Disease: Chlamydia
```

Comment: If there are two entries with the same name but a different disease, *which* do you want to be removed?

Comment: I'd like both of them to be removed or not to copy them to another ArrayList. If they are exact duplicates, I want to print / copy one of them.

Comment: It looks like Map of name -> disease (or list of diseases) will be better for you.

Comment: in case of line 5 and 6 what should happen as names are same.

Comment: BOTH should be removed, since the diseases are different.

Comment: you mean to say entries with same name should be removed whatever is the disease. right?

Comment: Same Name, Different Disease -> Remove Both!
One Instance -> Keep
Same Name, Same Disease -> Keep, but only one copy!

Comment: Can you also post the implementation of `IdenPerson#equals()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using `Map<String, Set<String>>`. Please have a look at this approach.

Basically, I am maintaining a `Set<String>` to hold the diseases. If a name has same disease, then the `Set` should have a **single value**, and if a name has multiple, then the `Set` should have **multiple entries**.

I am **eliminating** the value where Set has **multiple entries**

```
public class ArrayListDisease {

    public static List<String> process(List<String> input) {

        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

        for(String s : input) {
            String [] nameAndDisease = s.split("\\.");
            if(map.containsKey(nameAndDisease[0])) {
                Set<String> diseases = map.get(nameAndDisease[0]);
                diseases.add(nameAndDisease[1]);
            }
            else {
                Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
                set.add(nameAndDisease[1]);
                map.put(nameAndDisease[0], set);
            }
        }

        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(Entry<String, Set<String>> e : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = e.getKey();
            Set<String> values = e.getValue();
            if(values.size() == 1) {
                res.add(key+"."+values.iterator().next());
            }
        }
        return res;
    }


    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
        input.add("Name: Aimee Cholmondeley. Disease: German measles");
        input.add("Name: Colin Anissina.     Disease: Diphtheria");
        input.add("Name: Colin Anissina.     Disease: Malaria");
        input.add("Name: Aimee Cholmondeley. Disease: Typhoid fever");
        input.add("Name: Isaias Cheung.      Disease: Haemophilus Influenza");
        input.add("Name: Isaias Cheung.      Disease: Scarlet fever");
        input.add("Name: Sebastian Cutting.  Disease: Gingivitis");
        input.add("Name: Juan Weiss.         Disease: Acquired Immunodeficiency Sydrome (AIDS)");
        input.add("Name: Kaelyn Nauman.      Disease: Amebiasis");
        input.add("Name: Kaelyn Nauman.      Disease: Human Pulmonary Syndrome (HPS)");
        input.add("Name: Lyndsey Stapleton.  Disease: Chlamydia");
        input.add("Name: Lyndsey Stapleton.  Disease: Chlamydia");

        System.out.println(process(input));
    }

}
```

And here's the output

```
[Name: Lyndsey Stapleton.  Disease: Chlamydia, Name: Juan Weiss.         Disease: Acquired Immunodeficiency Sydrome (AIDS), Name: Sebastian Cutting.  Disease: Gingivitis]
```

Comment: Works pretty well. Thanks :)!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you can use additional libraries, this solution is based on that. Pull in [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and make use of a [`MultiMap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html):

```
LinkedListMultimap<String, String> mappedPersons = LinkedListMultimap.create();

for (int i = 0; i < IDArray.size(); i++) {
    IdenPerson person = IDArray.get(i);
    mappedPersons.put(person.name, person.dis);
}

List<IdenPerson> uniques = new ArrayList<IdenPerson>(mappedPersons.size());
for(int i = 0 ; i < IDArray.size(); i++) {
    if(mappedPersons.get(IDArray.get(i).name).size() == 1) {
        uniques.add(IDArray.get(i));
    }
}
```

Code needs cleanup, and can be optimized, but you get the gist.

On a side note, you should definitely follow better naming standards and use proper accessor/mutators for your Java objects.

*New side note: next time, please indicate if the question is related to an assignment or homework. Giving near complete solutions in such cases does not help you in the long run*

---

If you cannot pull in other libraries for any reason, you can accomplish the task in the same way, by replacing the multimap with a map/list combo:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> mappedPersons =
    new HashMap<String, Set<String>>(IDArray.size());

for (int i = 0; i < IDArray.size(); i++) {
    IdenPerson person = IDArray.get(i);
    List<String> diseases = mappedPersons.get(person.name);
    if(diseases == null) {
        diseases = new HashSet<String>(4);
        mappedPersons.put(person.name, diseases);
    }

    diseases.add(person.dis);
}

List<IdenPerson> uniques = new ArrayList<IdenPerson>(mappedPersons.size());
for(int i = 0 ; i < IDArray.size(); i++) {
    if(mappedPersons.get(IDArray.get(i).name).size() == 1) {
        uniques.add(IDArray.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use external libraries. School servers won't support it.

Comment: The multimap isnt strictly necessary. See edits for an alternate to it.

Comment: `uniques` will still contain entries if the name is the same but the disease is different. OP wants to remove such entries. You'd need to iterate through the diseases or use a `Set<String>`.

Comment: @DeepakBala - not sure how you figure that. Given the same name and different diseases the mapped list will have size > 1.

Comment: @Perception argh ! Sorry I mixed my words. I meant to say same name + same disease. Since the disease is maintained in a list it's value can be >1 even when there are duplicates. It will not make it to uniques as a result. That is use case #3 and not #1.

Comment: @DeepakBala - indeed, that is correct. I should probably go to bed now.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily with a `Map<String,IdenPerson>`. Override the equals() and hashCode() of IdenPerson to return true when the name and disease are the same. Before inserting an entry with `put('name',person)`, check for the entry with `get('name')`. Depending on the match, do the following.

> Same Name, Different Disease -> Remove Both!

If it matches an entry, check the disease and remove the entry if necessary. The person `equals()` match will return true if both the name and the disease are the same.

> One Instance -> Keep Same Name

That should be simple too. If there is one instance of the name, a get() will not find the key ever.

> Same Name, Same Disease -> Keep, but only one copy!

A get will match an existing entry but the disease will be the same and `equals()` will return true, so no action is necessary. Keep the existing entry and move on.

Answer (score 0):

Pseodo code:

Add `found` boolean. Initialize it to `false` and if you find duplicate, set it to `true`.
Then - at the end of the loop check if found is false. If so - add it as it a unique name.